# How to call vue.js object inside Background-image:url

Tags: html, css, image, vue.js, url

I have this `div` which render image using `background-image url` the first code below works fine which in the static way

**works fine**

```
<div class="image-input-wrapper" style="background-image:url(/storage/images/validations/my_main_image.png)"></div>
```

but when I putting the value of the image based on the obj like the code below it's not working

**not working**

```
<div class="image-input-wrapper" style="background-image:url('/storage/images/validations/'+emvdetailsdata[0].card_image)"></div>
```

Is there's any wrong of implementation in my second example?

**vuejs**

```
module.exports = function(data) {
  var _data = {
      config: null,
      n: 1,
      emvdetailsdata: Object,
};
return{
 data: (() => Object.assign({}, data, _data)),
    props: {
        data_object: Object,
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init();
 },
methods:{
  init(){
    this.functionexample();
  }
}

functionexample(){
   this.emvdetailsdata = objt["emv"];
}}
```

Comment: Try do `{ backgroundImage: 'url(/storage/images/validations/' + cardImage + ')' }` and add on vue code `this.cardImage = this.emvdetailsdata[0].card_image;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Vue to calculate some attribute, then you need to bind it.

With

```
v-bind:style="...
```

of

```
:style="..
```

If you don't do it, your style attribute will just have the text you pass to it.

This

```
style="background-image:url('/storage/images/validations/'+emvdetailsdata[0].card_image)"
```

should be changed to

```
:style="'background-image:url(\'/storage/images/validations/\'' + emvdetailsdata[0].card_image + ')'"
```

or using JS [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
:style="`background-image:url('/storage/images/validations/${emvdetailsdata[0].card_image})`"
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const App = {
  setup() {
    const emvdetailsdata = ref([ { card_image: 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-f2XX6_CJNNc/VCaHU7fHwJI/AAAAAAAAGig/ORo4Kah5u-Q/s1600/simple-gray-texture.jpg' } ]);
    return { emvdetailsdata }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div style="background-image:url(emvdetailsdata[0].card_image)">div 1</div>
  <div :style="'background-image:url(' + emvdetailsdata[0].card_image + ')'">div 2</div>
  <div :style="`background-image:url(${emvdetailsdata[0].card_image})`">div 3</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```